# Kotlin: Curly braces around several expressions (or statements)

Tags: scala, types, expression, kotlin

I think this question is somewhat related to [Kotlin function declaration: equals sign before curly braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36037442/kotlin-function-declaration-equals-sign-before-curly-braces)

In Scala, every statement is an expression (possibly with `Unit` type). If we surround multiple expressions with braces, then the final expression is the actual value of the curly braced part. Therefore,

```
// Scala
val a = {
  val b = 1
  val c = b + b
  c + c
}
println(a)
```

The type of `a` is `Int` and the code prints the value `4`.

However, in Kotlin, this is somewhat different.
If we do the same thing in the Kotlin,

```
// Kotlin
val a = {
  val b = 1
  val c = b + b
  c + c
}
println(a)
```

The type of `a` is `() -> Int` and the code prints the `Function0<java.lang.Integer>`, which means a 0-ary function object with result type `Int`.

So if we want to print the value `4`, we need to do `println(a())`.

In fact, the expression `{}` in Kotlin is a function `() -> ()`.

I cannot find an explanation about this in Kotlin official reference pages. Without a parameter list or `->`, curly braces make a function?

When I use Scala, I write many codes like the first code. However, in Kotlin, it **creates** a function object and we have to **call** the function, which may be an overhead in a loop or recursion.

1. Is there any document about this thing: *just curly braces make a function object*?
2. Any way to workaround the overhead in the second code if it is used many times?

**EDIT**

Here is the actual code that iterates many times:

in Java

```
while ((count = input.read(data, 0, BYTE_BLOCK_SIZE)) != -1) {
    ....
}
```

in Scala

```
while {
  count = input.read(data, 0, BYTE_BLOCK_SIZE)
  count != -1
} {
  ....
}
```

in Kotlin

```
while ({
    count = input.read(data, 0, BYTE_BLOCK_SIZE)
    count != -1
}()) {
    ...
}
```

You can see, only Kotlin makes a lot of function objects and calls them.

Comment: The `while` code does not seem to be idiomatic for reading. Wouldn't it better to use (buffered) streams for that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In Kotlin `{}` are always a lambda expression or a part of a syntax construct like `while(true) {}`. Probably different from Scala, but easy to grasp, nonetheless.

What you probably want is:

```
val a = run {
  val b = 1
  val c = b + b
  c + c
}
println(a)
```

Kotlin has no build-in concept of "code blocks anywhere". Instead we use standard functions-helpers like `run` in the example above.

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html

Comment: Note that unlike the other solutions, this one doesn't generate any anonymous classes and is therefore more efficient.

Answer (score 7):

If `{}` defines a function, you can just call the function upon declaring it, which will immediately evaluate it:

```
val a = {
  val b = 1
  val c = b + b
  c + c
}()
println(a)
```

prints `4`. (Note the `()` at the end of the block)

Answer (score 3):

> In Scala, every statement is an expression (possibly with Unit type)

That's not exactly true. Check: [Is everything a function or expression or object in scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10022408/is-everything-a-function-or-expression-or-object-in-scala)

As Zoltan said `{}` defines functions so instead of:

```
// Kotlin
val a = {
  val b = 1
  val c = b + b
  c + c
}
println(a)
```

it should be:

```
// Kotlin
val a = {
  val b = 1
  val c = b + b
  c + c
}
println(a()) //you defined a function, which returns `4`, not expression
```

or

```
// Kotlin
val a = {
  val b = 1
  val c = b + b
  c + c
}() //note these braces
println(a)
```

If you would like to print a value, not function, you can try to declare the variable and then use one of Kotlin functions to change a value like in example below:

```
var sum = 0
ints.filter { it > 0 }.forEach {
  sum += it
}
print(sum)
```

> Read: [Higher-Order Functions and
>   Lambdas](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html)

Hope it will help