# If-else expression in slick run, update method scala function

Tags: scala, if-statement, slick

I want to check with if-else statement if the variable
    newPsInfo.clearedCanLoadSC

is true then i want to make a Timestamp of Today else of some other Date 
so i tried the

```
ternary if-else with 
condition? true : false

newPsInfo.clearedCanLoadSc.equals(true) ? 
LocalDate.now() : LocalDate.of(2000,1,1)
```

but unfortunately doesn't work

First I .filter by _.id then I .map the results by productSettingsTable class to the new updated values of new productSettingsInfo parameter.
So my question is can i insert an if - else statement into the .map or .update methods like this:

```
    newPsInfo.clearedCanLoadSc.equals(true) ? 
    LocalDate.now() : LocalDate.of(2000,1,1))
```

```
def update(employer: Employer, newPsInfo: PsInfo): Future[Int] =

    db.run(
      productSettingsQuery.filter(_.employerId === employer.id).map(productSettings =>
        (productSettings.enableSc, productSettings.enableConversion,
          productSettings.enableRefundDays, productSettings.enableOutOfPocketPayment,
          productSettings.clearedCanLoadSc, productSettings.enableL, productSettings.clearedAt)).
     update((newPsInfo.enableSc, newPsInfo.enableConversion,
          newPsInfo.enableRefundDays, newPsInfo.enableOutOfPocketPayment,
          newPsInfo.clearedCanLoadSc, newPsInfo.enableL,newPsInfo.clearedCanLoadSc.equals(true) ? LocalDate.now() : LocalDate.of(2000,1,1)))
    )
```

The problem is that my if else clause is not working the Intelli j shows errors Cannot resolve symbols ?

So is there a way to insert an if-else-statement into the .map or .update function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala does not have a terinary conditional operator. Instead simply use if-else expression like so

```
if (newPsInfo.clearedCanLoadSc) LocalDate.now() else LocalDate.of(2000,1,1)
```

Note that if-expression is indeed an *expression* that evaluates to a value, not a control structure, for example

```
val x: String = if (true) "foo" else "bar"
x // res0: String = foo
```

Addressing the comment, control structures are constructs such as while loop, or if-then conditionals, and their purpose is to alter the flow of program control on the basis of some program state. Now, Scala obviously has those, but we say they are [expressions](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#conditional-expressions) because not only do they change the execution flow, they also [evaluate to a value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10029607/5205022). Contrast this with Java's if statement:

```
String x = if (true) "foo" else "bar";
```

which results in error

```
error: illegal start of expression
String x = if (true) "foo" else "bar";
```

Note how we are unable to evaluate it and assign it to variable `x`.

Comment: What you mean by controll structure can you give example