# Why does Scala fail to compile this function as tail recursive?

Tags: scala, recursion, tail-recursion

If I replace the first line of the following recursive depth first search function with the lines commented out within the foreach block, it will fail to compile as a tail recursive function (due to the @tailrec annotation) even though the recursion is still clearly the last action of the function. Is there a legitimate reason for this behavior?

```
@tailrec def searchNodes(nodes: List[Node], visitedNodes: List[Node], end: String, currentLevel: Int) : Int = {
    if (nodes.exists(n => n.id == end)) return currentLevel
    val newVisitedNodes = visitedNodes ::: nodes
    var nextNodes = List[Node]()
    nodes.foreach(n => {

        /*
        if (n.id == end){
            return currentLevel
        } 
        */
        nextNodes = nextNodes ::: n.addAdjacentNodes(visitedNodes)
    })
    if (nextNodes.size == 0) return -1
    return searchNodes(nextNodes, newVisitedNodes, end, currentLevel + 1)
}
```

Comment: 1. `if` without `else` ~> `Any`, and break recursion. 2. Do not use `return` (and avoid writing `Scala` as-if it were Java).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the other answer explains, using `return` in scala is a bad idea, and an anti-pattern. But what is *even worse* is using a `return` inside a lambda function (like your commented out code inside `foreach`): that actually throws an exception, that is then caught outside to make the main function exit.

As a result, the body of your function is compiled into something like:

```
def foo(nodes: List[Node]) = {
  val handle = new AnyRef
  try {
     nodes.foreach { n => 
       if(n.id == "foo") throw new NonLocalReturnControl(handle, currentLevel)
     ...
     foo(nextNodes)
  } catch {
     case nlrc: NonLocalReturnControl[Int] if nlrc.key == handle => nlrc.value
  }
}
```

As you can see, your recursive call is not in a tail position here, so compiler error is legit.

A more idiomatic way to write what you want would be to deconstruct the list, and use the recursion itself as the "engine" for the loop:

```
def searchNodes(nodes: List[Node], end: String) = {
  @tailrec def doSearch(
    nodes: List[(Node, Int)], 
    visited: List[Node], 
    end: String
  ) : Int = nodes match {
    case Nil => -1
    case (node, level) :: tail if node.id == end => level
    case (node, level) :: tail => 
      doSearch(
        tail ::: node.addAdjacentNodes(visited).map(_ -> level+1),
        node :: visited,
        end
      )
  }

  doSearch(nodes.map(_ -> 0), Nil, end)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure exactly what the compiler is thinking, but I think all your `return` statements [will be causing problems](https://blog.knoldus.com/scala-best-practices-say-no-to-return/).

Using `return` is an antipattern in scala - you don't need to write it, and you shouldn't. To avoid it, you'll have to restructure your `if ... return` blocks as `if ... value ... else ... other value` blocks.

This shape is possible because [everything is an expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10022471/1669475) (sort of). Your `def` has a value, which is defined by an `if ... else` block, where the `if` and the `else` both have values, and so on all the way down. If you want to ignore the value of something you can just put a new line after it, and the return value of a block is always the value of the last expression in it. You can do that to avoid having to rewrite your `foreach`, but it would be better to [write it functionally, as a `map`](https://www.brunton-spall.co.uk/post/2011/12/02/map-map-and-flatmap-in-scala/).